# Сократить условие в котлине

Tags: android, kotlin

Возможно ли сократить данное условие?

```
if (userType == SignActivity.Type.SIGN_UP) AppResources.getString(R.string.new_user)
            else AppResources.getString(R.string.register))
```

Comment: оно не выглядит огромным, чтобы его сокращать. Можно заменить на тернарный оператор, но вряд ли будет какой-то большой выигрыш

Comment: Ну как по мне AppResources.getString бросается в глаза, возможно имеет смысл заменять только id строкового ресурса.

Comment: @Grundy в котлине нет тернарного оператора, только `if-else`, в вообще да, я бы да, возвращал не строку, а только её id

Comment: @andreich, ну в принципе `// As expression 
val max = if (a > b) a else b` можно посчитать тернарным оператором :-)

Comment: [Control Flow](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну я бы так попробовал преобразовать

```
 AppResources.getString(if (userType == SignActivity.Type.SIGN_UP) R.string.new_user
            else R.string.register)
```

Comment: как-то не сильно сократилось :)

Comment: Еще можно SignActivity.Type.SIGN_UP статически экспортнуть

Comment: @Grundy ну пока это мой максимум))